# Insert query not working - Incorrect query or constraint violation

Tags: sql, metamug

I've created a sample resource file for testing on metamug's API.

```
<Resource v="0.8" xmlns="http://xml.metamug.net/resource/1.0">
  <Request method="GET" >
    <Query>
      insert into todo(a) values (1921)
    </Query>
  </Request>
</Resource>
```

But getting error as

```
{
    "message": "Incorrect query or constraint violation",
    "status": 409
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use `Update` tag for this operation not `Query` tag, so your resource file must be

```
<Resource v="0.8" xmlns="http://xml.metamug.net/resource/1.0">
  <Request method="GET" >
    <Update>
      insert into todo(a) values (1921)
    </Update>
  </Request>
</Resource>
```

See [Metamug Query and Update tag](https://metamug.com/docs/resource-file.php#query-and-update-tag)

Comment: @Sorter you might as well want to use `POST` method to perform `insert` operations